# display url slug instead of id in mvc

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have a blogging application and users are able to create posts, I used Entity framework to create the model from the database. In Posts I have an entry for `UrlSlug`.

However when I check the details of a post:

**Controller:**

```
    public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {
        Post post = db.Posts.Find(id);
        if (post == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(post);
    }
```

It returns a url with `id` at the end: `http://localhost:52202/Post/Details/1`

I have tried returning post.UrlSlug (throws an error) aswell as changing my RouteConfig.cs file to use `urlslug` instead of `id` (which does display the urlslug, but it cant find the page because of the controller). How can I change this so urlslug is displayed instead of the Post Table `Id`?

**RouteConfig.cs**

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

**View:**

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i += 3)
{
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var item in Model.Skip(i).Take(3))
        {
            <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
                <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Post", new { id = item.Id })">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="">
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Post", new { id = item.Id })">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</a>
                </h3>

                <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShortDescription)</p>

            </div>
        }

    </div>
}

@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, pageSize = Model.PageSize }))
```

**Edit**

An issue I noticed is on this line:

```
    public ActionResult Details(string urlslug)
    {
        Post post = db.Posts.Find(urlslug); //find only finds an eitity with a given primary key, how can I change this to find the string urlslug
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC: Routing custom slugs without affecting performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494184/asp-net-mvc-routing-custom-slugs-without-affecting-performance)

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11496379/2907017

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An action method does not dictate the URL, it only matches a request. You need to print the slug:

```
@Url.Action("Details", "Post", new { slug = item.Slug })
```

Then add to the routing to support the URL structure you want:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "PostWithSlug",
    url: "Post/Details/{slug}",
    defaults: new {  }
```

And alter the action method:

```
public ActionResult Details(string slug)
{
}
```

But besides that, you *do* want an ID in the URL. Otherwise you can't use the same post title twice.

Comment: is this a secondary routes.MapRoute or is this in place of the generic one?

Comment: You shouldn't need a new route or even edit the old one.  Simply creating the `public ActionResult Details(string slug)` should work as it is already looking for that pattern in the default route.

Comment: string slug does not work with Post.Find tho? (see updated question)

Comment: @Jacob you do for the "nice" URL, otherwise it'd become? slug=. One could also use attribute routing.

Comment: @Garrith use First(m => m.UrlSlug == urlslug).

Comment: @CodeCaster OP was never clear about the need for a 'nice' url.

Comment: @Jacob no, but it's implied by OP talking about slugs. If he didn't care about the URL, the ID would've been enough already.

Answer (score 0):

You can either rename your argument in your controller to match the 'slug' name. So instead of

```
public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
```

Use

```
public ActionResult Details(int urlslug = 0)
```

Alternative is to remove id from your route config like

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
    );
```

Keep in mind, what ever you argument name is in your Action, that name is used as the GET variable in your url.  So if the argument is int id, then your url must be like ?id=1.

Comment: Then change the type from int to string

Comment: @GarrithGraham you tried what?  Paste what you tried.

Comment: The type of one of the primary key values did not match the type defined in the entity. See inner exception for details.\r\nParameter name: keyValues

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75737/discussion-between-jacob-roberts-and-garrith-graham).

Comment: Agreed, I appreciate your help tho! On another note this is the inner exception The argument types 'Edm.Int32' and 'Edm.String' are incompatible for this operation. Near WHERE predicate, line 1, column 62."}

Comment: Then your db context is requiring an int and you are passing a string.  Change it back to int or change your db model to use string.

Answer (score 0):

An issue I noticed on the below line:

```
public ActionResult Details(string urlslug)
{
    Post post = db.Posts.Find(urlslug); //find only finds an eitity with a given primary key, how can I change this to find the string urlslug
```

You can select data with the help of urlslug by using Where instead of Find

i.e. `Post post = db.Posts.Where(x=> x.urlslug == urlslug).FirstOrDefault();`