# Routing method for a CMS like in .Net Core MVC

Tags: c#, routes, url-rewriting, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to build a CMS like website.

I have a Backend (admin website) where users can create or update pages for the Frontend (it will be 2 differents websites but both are .Net Core 6 MVC)

I've already done that with Asp.Net MVC by directly manipulating the [RouteCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.routing.routecollection?view=netframework-4.8) of the Front. The Backend was calling an action on the Front that was creating/updating the needed route for the purpose of url rewriting)

Here how I define Route url of all Pages in Front :

```
        var pages = _pageService.GetAll();
        foreach (CmsPage page in pages)
        {
            routeCollection.MapRoute(
                    name: $"page-{page.PageId}",
                    url: page.url,
                    defaults: new
                    {
                        controller = "PageController",
                        action = "Detail",
                        id = page.PageId,
                    }
                );
        }
```

This way, in Razor, I can easily list all page's link like this :

```
@foreach (CmsPage page in Pages)
{
    <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("page-" + page.PageId)">@page.Title</a>
}
```

If Users in Backend want to change the slug of a Page, the Backend call the Front so he can change the needed entry in the RouteCollection and update the slug :

```
 protected void UpdateRouteFromRouteTable(string routeName, string newUrl)
 {
        // Get the route by name
        var route = RouteTable.Routes[routeName];

        using (RouteTable.Routes.GetWriteLock())
        {
            ((Route)(route)).Url = newUrl;
        }
 }
```

By doing this the slug of the page is updated on the Front.

THIS is no more possible in .Net Core (can't access routeTable) but I need to achieve the same goal maybe with some kind of dynamics routing.

Where should I look ? I read about [DynamicRouteValueTransformer](https://medium.com/@fedonman/dynamic-controller-routing-in-asp-net-5-ac81a6bb8a95) but it doesn't seems to be what I'm looking for, neither seems to be Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite.RewriteContext...

Any hints ?

Thx a lot

Comment: Route in asp.net Core is different from ASP.Net;

In ASP.net, the routes registed in RegistRoutes Method which is called in Application_Start method in global.asax.cs,it would only be excuted when the application start.



However,in asp .net core the Route is registed in Middleware( would be invoked per request),So I think you may try with url rewrite or  try to regist a dynamic route

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#create-a-middleware-pipeline-with-webapplication

Comment: Thanks @ruika, dynamic route is defintly what I am looking for, and I'm going to try something like this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11496379/1143650